# Why BoundaryNorm from matplotlib not working as expected?

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar, imshow, boundary

I want to use [BoundaryNorm](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm.html) for mapping colors, since it maps values to integers. But I found the colormapping is not consistent given discreate image values.

I wrote test code below but found the color representation may change based on the image values.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap

bonds = [2, 5, 9]
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['black','blue', 'green','red'])
# cmap2.set_under('black')
# cmap2.set_over('red')
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bonds, cmap.N, extend='both')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8), nrows=1, ncols=2)

I1 = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 25]], dtype=np.uint8)
im = ax[0].imshow(I1, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, interpolation='none') 
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax[0])

I2 = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 255]], dtype=np.uint8)
im2 = ax[1].imshow(I2, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, interpolation='none') 
fig.colorbar(im2, ax=ax[1])

plt.show()
```

[colormapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eP30N.png)

The figure on the left is what I am expecting for I[2]=2 to be shown as blue. However, on the right side if I simply change the last value I[5]=255, I[2]=2 now mapped to black and I[3]=5 changed from green to blue. Why the right side is not mapping according the designed colorbar?

- v<2, black
- 2<=v<5, blue
- 5<=v<9, green
- v>9, red

Comment: Your ints are turned into floats inside the code, and making two floats exactly equal is non-trivial if any math is done to them.  Essentially think that 2 != 2.  Just make your bounds a bit larger or smaller.

Comment: As Jody Klymak notes, floats are only approximating. Internally, the norm maps values to the range 0-1, and colormapping maps these to a color. You could try `bonds = [1.9999, 4.9999, 8.9999]` to make sure `2` falls into the desired range.

Comment: Thanks JodyKlymak and JohanC, so if I understand correctly, the values in array I are converted into float before put into the 4 bins I listed above. I tried the bonds = [1.9999, 4.9999, 8.9999], which works correctly, thank you @JohanC. But since I am using BoundaryNorm, this boundary is not mapped to 0-1 right?